# How can I plot a bubble chart of given terms on y axis over years using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, charts

I've been trying to plot something similar to this using my dataframe on python but couldn't do so ! could anyone help please.
[image]

My dataframe is like this, I want to have years on the x-axis and the name of columns on the y-axis, the bubbles refer to the numeric value in each column.
[image]

Comment: Could you share what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to achieve a plot similar to the one I shared (Trend topics). 
The aim is to plot the frequency of each topic (how many related papers are  published ) over the years. For example, 279 papers were published using graph theory in 2023, 430 in 2022. For Machine learning (ML), 833 papers were published, etc.